# Hbase Heavy write Exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase

This Exception was raised in HBase, when there is a heavy writing to
 clusters:

```
 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server listener on 60020: readAndProcess threw exception java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer. Count of bytes read: 0
 java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer.channelRead(HBaseServer.java:1676)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Connection.readAndProcess(HBaseServer.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Listener.doRead(HBaseServer.java:703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(HBaseServer.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Listener$Reader.run(HBaseServer.java:470)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And this warning is raised:

```
 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: (responseTooSlow): {"processingtimems":761893,"call":"multi(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MultiAction@5bf92021), rpc version=1, client version=29, methodsFingerPrint=54742778","client":"172.16.0.121:55803","starttimems":1378784998180,"queuetimems":0,"class":"HRegionServer","responsesize":0,"method":"multi"}

 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server Responder, call multi(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MultiAction@5bf92021), rpc version=1, client version=29, methodsFingerPrint=54742778 from 172.16.0.121:55803: output error
  WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 39 on 60020 caught: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:135)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer.channelIO(HBaseServer.java:1710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer.channelWrite(HBaseServer.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Responder.processResponse(HBaseServer.java:924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Responder.doRespond(HBaseServer.java:1003)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Call.sendResponseIfReady(HBaseServer.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1346)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by not heavy write but big write. `"processingtimems":761893` means the write operation is not finished in 761 sec. And before the action is finished, client is timeout. Try to reduce the multi operation item count.